# To set goal for Dynamic URL for an E-commerce Project

Tags: google-analytics, dynamic-url

URL : https://steroidsoutletuk.com/checkout-2/?order=1324&key=wc_order_jYwEIF1DEuCjf 
& URL is always changes after checkout-2 means this only (order=1324&key=wc_order_jYwEIF1DEuCjf)when a user place an order for it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any filters applied to the GA View that change the default reporting behavior of pages in the Behavior > Site Content > All Pages report, such as a cross-domain filter?

If not, create a destination goal with regex as the goal match type and enter ^/checkout-2/.*$ as the goal url.

If there is a filter being used that prepends the hostname to the requestURI, create a destination goal with regex as the goal match type and enter ^https://steroidsoutletuk.com/checkout-2/.*$ as the goal url.